# how to add Authorization on whole site MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I have 2 controllers in my site, one of them is for the login page and the rest is my actual application. My login works correctly at the moment, it will check my DB and redirect to the page needed.

But what i don't know what is the best way to do is have an actual authorization check, cause if someone writes the redirected url they will also load the page. i researched and came up with Owin, but it seems too complex, is it the best way to go?

Comment: If it is a rather small application, you can use a session cookie that is valid for the duration of the session and use that cookie as the authorisation token.

Comment: Are you aware of  [`authentication`](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication) and [`authorization`](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authorization) configuration sections of web.config? They can also be mixed with [`location`](https://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/deep-dive-into-iis-configuration-with-iis-7-and-iis-8) section to specify different rules for different URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own `AuthorizeAttribute` and overrid the `AuthorizeCore` method

1. When user login - you add a token to session like

   ```
   Session["IsLogin"] = true;
   ```
2. Create a attribute which inherit `AuthorizeAttribute` and overrid `AuthorizeCore` such that:

   ```
   public class SimpleAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
   {

       protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
       {
          if(Session["IsLogin"] != null && Session["IsLogin"] == true)
          {
             return true;
          }
          else
          {
             return false;
          }
       }
   }
   ```
3. apply the attribute to your controller

   ```
   [SimpleAuthorize]
   public class NeedLoginController : Controller
   {
   }
   ```
4. If you want to change where user will be redirected to when not authorized, you can either set it at the `web.config`

   ```
   <authentication mode="Forms">
     <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" />
   </authentication>
   ```

   or override `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` such that:

   ```
   protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
   {
       filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                   new RouteValueDictionary(
                       new
                           { 
                               controller = "Account", 
                               action = "Login" 
                           })
                   );
   }
   ```

AuthorizeAttribute is what called `action filter` in asp .net mvc 
for more info about action filter in general, please checkout tutorial such as this one from msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410209(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: where should this class be created in? a model? or the actual controller?

Comment: also, is there a way with this method to redirect to some page if not authorized?

Comment: action filter is just a class, so you can put it anywhere you would like according to your solution structure - for me, typically I will have a folder where I put action filters.  Regard to redirect - check out the edit answer